# What is wrong with this powershell script?

Tags: powershell

Tried so hard, I can't figure out what's wrong with it. It might turn out to be something trivial and embarrassing, I give up

```
Param(
[string]$i = "",
 [int]$start,
 [int]$end,
 [int]$width,
 [int]$height,
 [string]$o = ""
)

if ($i.Length == 0 or $o.Length == 0 or ($width == 0 and $height == 0)) 
{
    Write-Host "input, output, either of width of height are required"
    Exit
}
$sum = $start + $end
if ( not ($sum==0) and ($sum == $start or $sum == $end))
{
    Write-Host "When either of the start or end is supplied, the other has to be supplied too"
    Exit
}

 $widthString = $width.ToString()
 $heightString = $width.ToString()

if (($width -ge 0) and $height==0) 
{
}
```

[image: Error shown on the ISE]

Comment: Well, one thing is that the line above it should probably be `$heightString = $height.ToString()` but I don't think that's causing your error.

Comment: The largest issue I see is the use of [comparison operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) you want to use `-eq` instead of `==` also `-and` instead of `and` etc

Comment: You've obviously picked up a number of functional concepts, but... everything is wrong with this script. Could you *describe* (in english) what you're actually trying to accomplish with this? A lot of the constraints that you're having trouble with could (and should) have been implemented in the `param` block, not inside the script

Comment: Please do not post questions that boil down to "please read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) to me".

Answer (score 5):

You've tagged this as PowerShell so I assume this is the language you're trying to write in?

Your tokens aren't valid in PowerShell, a decent list of comparisons/logic operators can be found [here](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html).

In short though, `==` should be `-eq`, `and` should be `-and`, `or` should be `-or` and so on.

Comment: `not` should also be `-not`